# Как получить url страницы сайта открытого во iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

На странице есть iframe:

```html
<iframe style="width:100px;height:100px" id="frame" name="tree" src="https://ru.stackoverflow.com" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Я хочу сделать на сайте кнопку:

```
<button id="click">Get URL</button>
```

И чтобы при нажатии на нее выдавался URL страницы открытой во фрейме.

Гуглил, оказывается если во фрейме открыт другой домен - то не отдает URL.

Как решить эту задачу? Во фрейме всегда открыт другой домен...

Может быть есть какая-то похожая альтернатива фрейму?...

Comment: другой домен ваш?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, не мой

Comment: а значение Вы хотите получить, даже если внутри iframe произошел переход по ссылке?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, там в основном и будет происходить переход по ссылкам внутри фрейма. то есть чел заходит на мой сайт, там во фрейме ему загружает другой сайт, он ходит там внутри фрейма, нажимает на мою кнопку **Get URL** и ему выдается `alert(url)` страницы сайта который во фрейме

Comment: есть альтернативы iframe - object или embed, однако способа получить актуальный урл из них мене не известен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а можете привести пример альтернатив? Или ссылочку

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5